# How to display a component or not in a view without using many lines of code

Tags: angular

I have seen many examples but I still believe that there can be an easier way without the need to include code in each component that is created. My idea is not to show 2 components in my login, but in the rest of my components, yes.

```
app.component.html

<menu></menu>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer_component></footer_component>
```

Comment: question is not clear. just remove the selectors if you are not using it

Comment: Add an ngIf in your main component which controls the visibility of the child components - ngIf can have condition on either HTML or TS file

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to render all the components in the app.component.html , you could use the *ngIf directive with condition

```
<menu *ngIf="condition"></menu>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer_component *ngIf="condition"></footer_component>
```